# Angular global utility function that is called by all of your Parse request error callbacks

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, error-handling

I am currently writing an angular app and I am refactoring my code reviewing all error handling. Currently my Angular app uses Parse.com and I must manage session tokens in the app. There is a specific recommendation by Parse.com on building a global utility function that should be called by all of your Parse request error callbacks. I am interested in building this global utility function, but I am uncertain about its implementation. I am guessing I should write it as a service and inject it in all of my controllers for error checking. Here is the Parse.com code

```
function handleParseError(err) {
  switch (err.code) {
    case Parse.Error.INVALID_SESSION_TOKEN:
      Parse.User.logOut();
      ... // If web browser, render a log in screen
      ... // If Express.js, redirect the user to the log in route
      break;

    ... // Other Parse API errors that you want to explicitly handle
  }
}

// For each API request, call the global error handler
query.find().then(function() {
    ...
}, function(err) {
  handleParseError(err);
```

});

https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#sessions-handling-invalid-session-token-error

I am guessing I should write a service implementing the error handling function like this

```
.service(ParseErrorHandler, function(){

   return{

         function handleParseError(err) {
            switch (err.code) {
             case Parse.Error.INVALID_SESSION_TOKEN:
               Parse.User.logOut();
               $scope.go('app.login');
               break;

              ... // Other Parse API errors that you want to explicit handle
              ...//List of Parse.com Error Codes to reference at link below
              ...////http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/
              ...//T_Parse_ParseException_ErrorCode.htm 
            }
        }
     }
 })
```

Then in my controllers I inject the ParseErrorHandler Service where necessary and I call the function in my error handler section of the function

```
query.find().then(function() {
  ...
}, function(err) {
  ParseErrorHandler.handleParseError(err);
});
```

Is this what is required to implement this recommendation from Parse? If so you can upvote my question perhaps? (Not familiar with SO)

Answer (score 0):

A service is the correct way to share/persist data across controllers. The code you provided looks solid. One suggest is that you should DRY your code up. I am assuming that you will be doing a lot of

```
function(err) {
  ParseErrorHandler.handleParseError(err);
}
```

You should turn this into a function:

```
function logError(err) {
  ParseErrorHandler.handleParseError(err);
}
```

This will make your code cleaner.

```
query.find().then(function() {
  ...
}, logError);
```

Comment: Do you mean:                                                                query.find().then(function() {
  ...
}, logError(err)) (added err as argument to logError in your code)

Comment: no it should just be logError as find is expecting a function not the results of a function. By doing logError(err) it would return the results of logError to find which find would not know what to do with it. find is expect a function that will take arguments.

Comment: Cool. Hats off to DRY. Advice taken